# Can different lookup lists be based on the same entity?

Tags: breeze

I have 1 entity 'Parameters' that keeps all values for different dropdown lists etc..
When I bundle these through the breeze lookups controller, they all get loaded nicely.
But since the manager maps them against the metadata, they all end up in 1 list.
How can I seperate them?

thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Can you add some additional detail?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using and resolved by:

1. Having breeze load the entity (Lookups) with only the values that I needed (all of my source values also had a category Id that I allowed me to identify the correct grouping.

   function getLookups() {
           return EntityQuery.from('Lookups')
                   .using(manager).execute()
                   .then(processLookups)
                   .fail(queryFailed);
       }
2. Once I had the "Lookup" entity loaded with breeze, I loaded the arrays in the view model by executing a query on the lookup entity and loading that array with the correct values.

   methods(datacontext.getMethods());

   var getMethods = function () {
           var query = EntityQuery
               .from('Lookups')
               .where('Cat_Id', 'eq', 375);

   ```
       return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
   };
   ```
3. In the view I bound the select to the view model array and set the value to the navigation property that tied back to the SQL lookup table.